# How to make a list of numbers that perfectly divide with 6000 or the most approach to 6000

Tags: javascript

I need to Make an program that calculate the perfect way of cut bars of 6000milimeters to Make indoor doors and Windows and i need to waste less I can everytime I cut there ia 2 mm that is wasted because of blade. So for example i Have this inputs: 2x1450 2x1600 3x1004 And neeed to show me how can i sort to give me perfect 6000 or the most aproach for example cut 1600+2x1450 And the next one cut 1600+3x1004 with 2 mm cut error at every input.So IT s like sort every inputs in grids of 6000mm.

```
function bign(){
var bignumber;
var nr1;
var nr2;
var nr3;
var bara = 6000;
var nrbuc1;
var nrbuc2;
var nrbuc3;
var bucx1;
var bucx2;
var bucx3;
```

```
 nr1=parseInt(document.getElementById("no1").value) 
 nrbuc1=parseInt(document.getElementById("buc1").value);
 nr2=parseInt(document.getElementById("no2").value);
 nrbuc2=parseInt(document.getElementById("buc2").value)
 nr3=parseInt(document.getElementById("no3").value);
 nrbuc3=parseInt(document.getElementById("buc3").value)
 
 bucx1=nr1 * nrbuc1;
 bucx2=nr2 * nrbuc2;
 bucx3=nr3 * nrbuc3; '

 
 var total1 = bucx1+bucx2;
 var total2 = bucx2+bucx3;
 var total3 = bucx1+bucx2+bucx3;
 var rezultat1= document.getElementById("VERIFICAT").innerHTML = nr1 + " plus " + nr2 + " result";
 var rezultat2= document.getElementById("VERIFICAT").innerHTML = nr2 + " plus " + nr3 + " rusult";
 var rezultat3= document.getElementById("VERIFICAT").innerHTML = nr1 + " plus " + nr2 + " plus" + nr3;
 var gresit = document.getElementById("VERIFICAT").innerHTML = "GRESIT";

 

 if (total1 % bara == 0){
    alert (rezultat1);
 }
 if (total2 % bara == 0){
    alert (rezultat2);
}
if (total3 % bara == 0){
    alert (rezultat3);
}
else (total1%bara != 0 || total2%bara != 0 || total3%bara !=0  )
alert(gresit);


}
```

Comment: Are these dimensions squares? All of the examples have a single length or is that 2mm x 1450mm or is it 2 x 1450mm?

Comment: it's 2x 1450mm 2 it's a piece for example for a window i have this dimenssion (1450 x 1000 x 1450 x 1000) so i made it to don't put 1450 twice and make it 2x1450, and the same thing with 1000 and put this both dimesons 2piecex1000mm.

Comment: So basically it's a 6000mm wide sheet and the length doesn't matter because every cut is edge to edge.

Comment: exactly after i cut the first piece from total of 6000 will remain for example if i cut one piece of 1450 from total of 6000 will remain 4550 - 2mm so the new total i have it's 4548 for the next cut. but yeah it's edge to edge.

Comment: you need to be more specific on this questions because the people who are trying to help you does not understand the goal or what is in fact the question. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**Details are commented in example**

```js
/**
 * Given a constant width and one or more smaller 
 * widths, find how many of the smaller widths can
 * be combined to get as close as possible to the
 * constant width (but not exceed it)
 * @param {number} sheet - The width limit that 
 *        cannot be exceeded
 * @param {rest<string>} ...points - The points to
 *        to cut widths to.
 */ 
class Chop {
  constructor(sheet, ...points) {
    this.sheet = sheet;
    this.points = [...points];
  }
  /**
   * A utility method that formats text
   * @param {any} data - Any input a JSON can handle
   * @param {boolean} noConsole - Determine whether
   *        data is to display in console or 
   *        returned. @default is false
   * @return {any} any output a JSON can handle
   */
  static log(data, noConsole = false) {
    if (noConsole) {
      return JSON.stringify(data).trim();
    }
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
  }
  /**
   * Given an array of number-strings, convert them
   * into a simple format. Each formatted number is
   * a width to be "cut"
   * @ return {array} - An array of numbers used to
   *   cut the widths
   */
  mark() {
    this.points = this.points.flatMap(str => {  
      /**
       * If a string has a space...
       * ...split the string at every space
       */
      if (str.includes(' ')) {
        let y = str.split(' ');
        y[0] = +y[0] + 2;
        y[1] = +y[1] + 2;
        return y;
      }
      /**
       * If a string has a "x"...
       * ...split string at every "x"...
       * ...each number to the left of "x" determines...
       * ...how many times the number on the right of "x" is 
       * repeated
       */
      if (str.includes('x')) {
        let x = str.split('x');
        x.splice(-1, 1, ' ' + (+x[1] + 2));
        return x[1]
          .repeat(x[0])
          .split(' ')
          .map(n => +n);
      }
      return (parseInt(str) + 2);
    });
    let order = this.points.sort((a, b) => a - b);
    Chop.log(order);
    return order;
  }
  
  /**
   * Separates the numbers that fit within the limit
   * and those that don't.
   * @return {array<array>} - An array of arrays
   */
  cut() {
    let sum = 0, cutoff, index;
    for (const [idx, num] of this.points.entries()) {
      if (num + sum > this.sheet) {
        cutoff = `Cutoff is ${num}mm at index: ${idx}`;
        index = idx;
        break;
      } else {
        sum = num + sum;
      }
    } 
    let done = this.points.slice(0, index);
    let notDone = this.points.slice(index);
    Chop.log( 
      `Sum of cut sections: ${sum}mm
      
      ${cutoff}`);
    return [done, notDone];
  }
}

let z = new Chop(6000, '2x1140', '1000', '3x500', '3000 5000');
Chop.log(z.mark());
Chop.log(z.cut());
```